# control paths not returning a value 3

Tags: c++

Its giving me an error saying not all controll paths return a value: please help.

```
int using_range()
{
    int Num;

    try{
        cout << "Please enter a integer between 1 and 10: ";
        cin >> Num;
        if ((Num > 10) || (Num < 0)){
            throw 77;
        }
        else if ((Num <= 10) || (Num >= 0)){
            cout << Num << " is in range\n";
            return 0;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    catch (int x){
        cout << "The number cannot be greater than 10, or less than zero. Error " << x << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Im not sure what to do

Comment: just change your `else if` to `else`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an `if` followed by an `else if`, but if both of these checks fail, there's nothing to return by default. Your code should prevent that from ever happening, but the compiler isn't smart enough to know with 100% certainty that you will never fail both `if` checks.

```
try{
    cout << "Please enter a integer between 1 and 10: ";
    cin >> Num;
    if ((Num > 10) || (Num < 0)){
        throw 77;
    }
    else if ((Num <= 10) || (Num >= 0)){
        cout << Num << " is in range\n";
        return 0;
        system("pause");
    }
    // <- if you get here, nothing is going to be returned
 }
```

An alternative approach might be to change your `else if` to just `else`

Answer (score 0):

So, just a quick explanation: When you have a function that expects a returned value (in your case, an `int`), the compiler is happy when **all** paths in your program actually do so. In this code, there *may* be a situation where it could land past your `if` and `else if`, in which case, it doesn't do anything. You could throw an error here or something if you wanted.

But one extra thing I wanted to add is to add some protection when receiving user input. That is, make sure the user entered a number!

Currently, if the user entered `b` for instance, the output would be `0 is in range`!

So, add another check to be sure:

```
int using_range()
{
    int Num;

    try{
        cout << "Please enter a integer between 1 and 10: ";
        cin >> Num;

        // this checks if whatever the user input can be parsed as an int.
        if (!cin){
           cout << "please enter a number." << endl;
           return -1;
        }
        else if ((Num > 10) || (Num < 0)){
            throw 77;
        }
        else if ((Num <= 10) || (Num >= 0)){
            cout << Num << " is in range\n";
            return 0;
            system("pause"); // also, this will never happen :)
        }
        else{
            // not sure how it could get here, but maybe in weird corner cases?
            return -1;
        }
    }
    catch (int x){
        cout << "The number cannot be greater than 10, or less than zero. Error " << x << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```